# Why is Rectangular density kernel not cut off at tails?

Tags: distributions, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

When we create kernel densities we could use different kernels. Here I create an example with Gaussian, Rectangular and Triangular kernel:

[image]

When we check the start and end points of the distributions they are all the same. We can see from the Gaussian and Triangular kernels that they smoothly curve to the edges. But the Rectangular kernel does hit the 0 density earlier. So I was wondering, why are the tails from the Rectangular kernels not cutoff at the point it hits 0 density? What is the purpose of showing the flat tail lines?

---

Code to create plot with example data:

```
set.seed(7)
values = runif(100, 0, 1)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(density(values,
     kernel = "gaussian"),
     main = "Gaussian", col = "red")
plot(density(values,
     kernel = "rectangular"),
     main = "Rectangular", col = "blue")
plot(density(values,
     kernel = "triangular"),
     main = "Triangular", col = "green")
plot(density(values,
     kernel = "gaussian"), col = "red", main = "All")
lines(density(values, kernel = "rectangular"), col = "blue")
lines(density(values, kernel = "triangular"), col = "green")
```

Comment: See the explanation under "Details" in the help page for `density`.